# Count data from various workbooks and sheets and paste it in one workbook

Tags: excel, vba, count

I want to count how many times the letter "T" appears in the checklist from various workbook(each consisting of around 11 sheets) and paste the final data in one workbook.

I have this code but i keep getting

> "error code 9"

I am pretty sure that i have defined the correct workbook. Is there any other ways to accomplish my final results? Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim x As Integer

Dim wash_count As Integer


'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents


For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then

        For x = 5 To 74
            If ws.Cells(x, 2).Value = "Wash" And (ws.Cells(x, 4).Value = "T") Then
            wash_count = wash_count + 1

            End If

        Next x

    End If
Next ws

wb1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsx")
wb1.Activate
wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("D6") = wash_count

'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error message but I guess [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Subscript_Out_of_Range) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Just and advice. You are looping 70 times in each worksheet of each workbook, and looking at your code, it looks like you just want to count how many rows contain value `Wash` in column B and value `T` in column D in range `B5:D74` always. I'm pretty sure you can substitute that loop for a COUNTIFS.Something like `application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("B5:B74"),"Wash",ws.Range("D5:D74"),"T")` should return the total `wash_count` in a worksheet. You don't need to do it 1 by 1

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to help :) I believe that the root cause of the issue was that you used 'wb1 =...' instead of 'set wb1 =..'. I made some additional edits and comments to the code and it seems to be working well for me. I am curious if it will resolve the issue for you too.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim x As Integer

Dim wash_count As Integer


'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

   With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents


    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then

            For x = 5 To 74
                If StrConv(ws.Cells(x, 2).Value, vbProperCase) = "Wash" And StrConv(ws.Cells(x, 4).Value, vbProperCase) = "T" Then 'added the StrConv to make sure you don't loose a case just because it was written in capital or lowercase letters
                wash_count = wash_count + 1

                End If

            Next x

        End If
    Next ws


    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsx") 'wb1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsx")
        'changed your code 'wb1 = Workbooks("Book3")' to set 'wb1 =...' as workbook variables need to be assigned with 'set' command
        'you might want to add some handling of whether the workbook 'Book3' is already opened and if not then to open it

    'this seem strange to me, I thought you wanted to count the 'T's in all of the workbooks
    'in the folder and then paste the final number to one place
    'which I thought was going to be wb1 'Book3'
    'if that was the case then the line 'wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("D6") = wash_count' should be
    '-> 'wb1.Sheets("Summary").Range("D6") = wash_count'
        'also I'd move the whole line after the loop and paste only the final wash_count in the very end
    wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("D6") = wash_count

    'Save and Close Workbook
          wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
          DoEvents

        'Get next file name
          myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: i seem to have an error of 'run time error "91" ' at the line 
   ' For Each ws In wb.Sheets'

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I can't seem to replicate the issue. Does it happen on the first run, or it runs fine for the first time and crashes later? And does the 'myFile' open properly? and if you used your original code and just add the 'set wb =' instead of 'wb = ', would that work?

Comment: hi i have tried it, i am still getting the error code 9, there is a total of 3 workbooks in my folder to test and each is named Book1, Book2 and Book3. The code doesnt seem to pass through Book1 as i tried replacing the file name to Book1 and it managed to get the msgbox to appear

Comment: Hi, I'm unable to replicate the issue, for me it's working fine (apart from that the wash_count is saved in each of  the 'xls' workbooks, not to the 'main' one). Would you please let me know where you want the final count to be saved? In a new workbook, to an existing workbook or to the workbook where the macro runs from? Also does the 'myFile' contain a value that makes sense before starting the for each ws loop (the set 'wb = ..' runs ok?

Comment: Hi, the final outcome i want is for the total summaries sum to be in one existing workbook in the same folder